# nullpointer exception on session retrieval

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, nullpointerexception

I have a problem where whenever I call `getStatusList()` for the third time by the `Lazy loader` on my profile page, the `user1.getEmail()` is giving me `nullpointer exception`. I think the `user1` is unable to fetch the User object from `frienddet`, is there something I am missing out. I would be grateful if some one could point out my error.

```
public List<Status> getStatusList() {
        EntityManager em;
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("FreeBird");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        User user1 = (User) session.getAttribute("frienddet");
            System.out.println(user1.getEmail());
        // some codes


    }
```

**EDIT**

It turns out `frienddet` is getting removed from the session after few calls to the `getStatusList()` But I have no idea why it is happening, I am not removing any attributes from the session with my codes.

Comment: Javascript != Java, dont tag it as a Javascript question when you are using java

Answer (score 1):

Your call `session.getAttribute("frienddet")` is returning null because `"frienddet"` isn't initialized (a guess on my part, it could be initialized to null).

Looking at your code you're not actually using the entity manager (I assume this is in the omitted code below). As such, you need to look at where `"frienddet"` is put into your session and find out why it is null there. If you jump into the debugger (which I would really recommend) you should see your session object missing a key/value pair or a key to a null.

Comment: I checked it out in the debugger, the key is null. I still don't get it why it working the first two times.

Comment: The thing you need to look for is WHERE that key is set. Odds are it is in another request. Where is "frienddet" set? That's the question.